# Lua: string expected error with parsing

Tags: lua

I'm trying to parse PHP page http://martinz.ru/bash/index.php:

```
function run(msg, matches)
    b = http.request("martinz.ru/bash/index.php")  -- line 8
    local hol = string.sub (b, 1)
    return hol
end
```

But console spews write error:

```
*** lua: plugins/hol.lua:8: bad argument #1 to 'sub' (string expected, got table)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: which line is line 8?

Comment: It would appear that `http.request` has returned a table instead of a string.

Comment: local hol = string.sub (b, 1) - line 8

Comment: Could You please specify the library and it's version You're using? Because it does not seam to be LuaSocket.

Comment: i'm use luarocks-2.2.0

Comment: All ok. http.request not eat cp1251